# No publish settings options for Azure function in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions, publish

Here's my publish tab for the Azure function v2.0:
[image]

I don't see any option to connect to the Azure function hosted on Azure.
Because of this I'm unable to setup `local.settings.json` for my function app.

Kindly help me fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have **Tools and choose the Azure Functions and Web Job Tools** extension installed?

Move to the **`Extensions and Updates`** under Tools menu. Here expand **`Installed - > Tools and choose the Azure Functions and Web Job Tools`**.